# What does this error tell us when I'm trying to run an example in Apache Mahout?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mahout

I am studying to use Apache Mahout, and get the following message after running one of its example:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/user1/workspace/LDAAnalysis/output/data
```

In fact, the directory of `*/output/data` was found to be created there after running. I don't understand what does this error message tell us?

Comment: I think you'd have to provide more info than this? it generally means the input dir you specified isn't OK. In particular I'm guessing it needs to be an HDFS path.

Comment: Sean, thanks for the reply. I am not familiar with Hadoop, and am trying to learn Mahout using single node. Based on what you said, I still need to setup path in an Hadoop way even on a normal linux box. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first big question is, "what example"? Some are going to work locally, some won't. I assume it's LDA-related, but would be very helpful to say. Or print more of the stack trace.

It is not merely a question of writing the path correctly. You have to have the right destination set up. From your comment I am not sure if you have Hadoop set up or not or whether HDFS if running or where you've put your input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The java file that I was trying to run is exactly the same from examples/src/main/java/orga/apache/mahout/clustering/syntheticcontrol/dirichlet/job.java    I did not install hadoop on my linux box. Is hadoop necessary for running mahout. I runned displayDirichlet.java, which worked just fine.

Comment: How about the command line? the input is the issue, but it's not so clear what your input is.

Comment: I also doubt that the input data does not have correct format. I am trying to geenerate one. It seems to me that the Mahout documentation is not very clear on this. Can you give me any suggestions? Or is there any public available data set,which is compatible to Mahout, and can be downloaded? I just want to test.

Comment: There isn't documentation -- you usually have to read the code. The first stage is org.apache.mahout.clustering.conversion.InputMapper, which expects input with lines like "2.5 3.3 3.9 ..." to specify vectors.

Comment: PS Again, it would really really be helpful to post your full error. I am still not clear on what the problem is as a result, and if you want help it's much easier to not guess!